# Adding Button to WPF DataGrid in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF application with WPF DataGrid. WPF DataGrid has attached itemsSource, which is
List of CSVRecord class instances. CSVRecord is class with public items which are displayed in cells of datagrid. List is dynamically updated from separate thread (one item in record holds download progress of each file). I want to have the ability to add one extra column to DataGrid in runtime. This column should contain buttons to stop corresponding downloads. I know how to stop download or so, but 
**I havent managed and that is my question, how to add Button to particular cell of datagrid (in runtime from C#, no XAML) and when clicking on it, getting known exact row of datagrid**.

Comment: Sounds like DataGrid abuse to me...

Comment: Do you have any code as a basis for us to appropriate an answer? Any given suggestion, although targeted at your scenario, might not be fit for purpose in your implementation. Obviously this would intuitively be done when binding the data, but what do you have so far?